# the affine scheme of an integral ring is integral

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$ be an affine scheme. In the book of Hartshone, he claimed that $X$ is integral if and only if $A$ is an integral domain. If $X$ is integral then we can deduce easily that $A$ is an integral domain.

How can I show that if $A$ is an integral domain then $X$ is integral ? Please give me some hint. Thanks.

Comment: This is just a matter of applying all of the relevant definitions. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @Quiaochu Yuan: The definition of Hartshone for an integral scheme is $O_{X}(U)$ is an integral domain for any open subset $U$ of $X$. So how can I apply it?

Comment: What is $O_X(Spec A)$? (and what does the definition imply about that)

Comment: @JohnC: Did you read my question ? If $X$ is integral then $O_{X}(X)=O_{X}(SpecA)=A$, therefore $A$ is an integral domain. What I can not prove is that if we have $A$ is an integral domain, then how can we prove that $X$ is integral.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks, I always think about some others tricks and forgets the definitions :|

Comment: With Hartshorne, Proposition II.3.1 (which says that 'integral' $\Leftrightarrow$ 'irreducible'+'reduced') this is relatively straightforward.

Comment: It is too strong Nils Matthes. On the other hand, Hartshorne did mentioned the equivalent condition for integral property before that proposition.

Comment: @Arsenaler: yes, from the strictly logical point of view, this is possibly too strong. However, I believe that Proposition II.3.1 gives the "correct" way of thinking about integrality of schemes. Why do I think so? Because integrality is neither a global notion (cannot be checked on global sections) nor a local notion (cannot be checked on stalks). But said proposition allows you to split integrality up into a global notion (irreducibility), and a local notion (reducedness). This yields a neat way of thinking about integrality, which may make life easier.

Comment: For example, the very desirable statement that a scheme $X$ is integral, if and only if all local rings are integral domains is not true. But if all local rings are integral domains (or even only reduced local rings), then the only possible obstacle to integrality of $X$ is the purely topological notion of irreducibility of the underlying topological space of $X$.

Comment: You can also think of it as "local rings are domains" + connected, I think.

Comment: @TTS: This is not true. A scheme $X$ is integral if and only if all of the following conditions hold: 1) $X$ is nonempty; 2) $X$ is connected; 3) the stalks of the structure sheaf of $X$ are integral; 4) the set of irreducible components of $X$ is locally finite. None of these conditions can be omitted.

Comment: @Fred Ah, right, I forgot a Noetherian hypothesis. Whoops!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $A$ is integral and let $U$ be a non-empty open subset of $\operatorname{Spec} A$. Let $f, g \in \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A}(U)$. By definition of $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A}(U)$ we have an open covering $U = \bigcup V_i$, such that $f|_{V_i} = f_i/s_i$ and $g|_{V_i} = g_i/t_i$. Now, $f|_{V_i}=0$ is equivalent to $f(Q) = 0$ for some $Q \in V_i$: if $f(Q) = 0$ for some $Q \in V_i$, then there exists $s \not\in Q$ such that $s f_i = 0$, and so $f_i=0 \Rightarrow f|_{V_i}=0$. Similarly for $g$.

Next, suppose that $f, g$ are non-zero but $fg=0$. Then there exist $P \in V_i$ and $Q \in V_j$, for some $i,j$, such that $f(P) \neq 0$ and $g(Q) \neq 0$. Suppose that $V_i \cap V_j \neq \emptyset$. Then for $P' \in V_i \cap V_j$ we must have $f(P')g(P') = 0$. Hence there exists some $s' \not\in P'$ such that $s' f_i g_j = 0$, which implies either $f|_{V_i \cap V_j} = 0$ or $g|_{V_i \cap V_j} = 0$. But this is a contradiction in view of the remark of the previous paragraph.

Hence it must be the case that $V_i \cap V_j = \emptyset $ and so $\operatorname{Spec} A = V_i^c \cup V_j^c, \, \, \, (*)$. Since $A$ is an integral domain, $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is irreducible, which contradicts $(*)$, since both $V_i^c, V_j^c$ are proper subsets. Hence either $f=0$ or $g=0$.